# XAML .Children property problems

Tags: c#, xaml, foreach, children

I am trying to filter through my `.XAML` file and set the `ItemSource` for numerous `ComboBox`es.  The issue that I'm having is that when it get to the bottom layer of the `foreach` loop, my degugger errors out with an obvious message of failed conversion...  Here's some code to clarify what the hell I'm talk about:

### XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spFruit" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel x:Name="spFruit1" Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto"  Width="250">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,0">
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbApple"  Content="Apples" Margin="0,5"></CheckBox>
            <Label Content="Quantity: " Margin="67,0,0,0"></Label>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxApple"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbApple, Path=IsChecked}"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,0">
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbApricot" Content="Apricots" Margin="0,5"></CheckBox>
            <Label Content="Quantity: " Margin="59,0,0,0"></Label>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxApricot" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbApricot, Path=IsChecked}"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

And so forth and so on...  (There's thousands of items, and we don't need to go through all of them.)  Now, the `ComboBox`es...  I'm initially trying to populate them with a `List<int>` (that I've populated already) like so:

### C#

```
foreach (StackPanel spVert in spFruit.Children)
    foreach (StackPanel sp in spVert.Children)
        foreach (ComboBox cmbx in sp.Children)
            cmbx.ItemsSource = lstComboContent;
```

Now, I thought (for my specific example) that this should iterate through all the controls within the lowest `StackPanel` (`sp`) and find the `ComboBox`es, and then assign their `ItemSource`.  Apparently, I was wrong, because when the code executes, it immediately stops on the very first `Checkbox` and gives me the error that it *Cannot Convert System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox to System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox*

My official question is this:
Why does the loop not just skip over the `Checkbox`?  Obviously , the Checkbox, Label and ComboBox are all children of the StackPanel, and if I tell the loop to look specifically for the ComboBox, why does it stop on (and not continue past) the Checkbox?

I am still pretty new to XAML, so please forgive my ignorance.  I thought I had a decent understanding of it until this snag.  Seems like a small thing to get hung up on, but here I am.  Thanks for all the help and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
foreach (ComboBox cmbx in sp.Children)
    cmbx.ItemsSource = lstComboContent;
```

`StackPanel` has 3 childrens - `CheckBox, Label, ComboBox`. In your `for` loop you iterate through all children but you try to cast every child to `ComboBox`. First child is `CheckBox` and you can't cast it to `ComboBox`. Your code should be:

```
foreach (StackPanel spVert in spFruit.Children)
    foreach (StackPanel sp in spVert.Children)
        foreach (var control in sp.Children)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof (ComboBox))
            {
                ((ComboBox)control).ItemsSource = lstComboContent;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow. I guess it always takes a fresh pair of eyes.  Thanks @Roma.  I'll give you that answer when it lets me.

Comment: this does give me 2 errors...  1: _'control' is a variable but used like a type_.  And 2: _'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemSource'_...

Comment: I actually tried that right after I said something.  The `if` statement works, but typecasting the control as a ComboBox doesn't...  Hmmmmmm....  Still gives the second error message...

Comment: @GeoffOverfield, see edited answer - added additional `()`